# Cloud Function should only fire when an image was added

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I´m looking for a solution to fire a Cloud Function only when an image was uploaded. I was playing around with functions and have seen [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions/index.js) code example and its working but I don't like the fact that the function is fired every time I upload a file. When I upload 1000 text files the function is executed 1000x and will break after detecting that the file was not an image. This behavior seems to be quite inefficient. Can I do declare that the function should only be fired for images on a more lower level to bypass the useless costs or is it possible to outsource the conditions? One solution could be to just use a bucket for images only but you may have other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your storage trigger will receive one event for every change made to your storage bucket.  There is currently no way to filter or limit the events that arrive at your function.  You have to check inside the function if the event is of interest to your function, perhaps by looking at the path, name, or type of the file that changed.

As you are seeing, this is not optimal to prevent unwanted invocations, but you can always file a [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to effectively vote for things you would like to see.